# How to update table data using group by in mysql

Tags: mysql

I got a situation where I have table with two columns(**col1, col2**) and I added boolean  column(**col3**). Now I have to update the rows with distinct col1 and first occurence of col2 (i.e) same as rows we get from group by col1 with **col3 as true**.

```
 create table my_table( col1 integer, col2 integer, col3 tinyint(1));

 insert into my_table(col1,col2) values(1,2);
 insert into my_table(col1,col2) values(1,1);
 insert into my_table(col1,col2) values(2,1);
 insert into my_table(col1,col2) values(2,2);
 insert into my_table(col1,col2) values(2,8);
 insert into my_table(col1,col2) values(3,2);
 insert into my_table(col1,col2) values(3,1);
 insert into my_table(col1,col2) values(3,5);
 insert into my_table(col1,col2) values(3,6);
 insert into my_table(col1,col2) values(4,3);
 insert into my_table(col1,col2) values(4,6);
 insert into my_table(col1,col2) values(4,5);
 insert into my_table(col1,col2) values(4,2);
```

When I added new column table has following values with col3 null.

```
 COL1   COL2    COL3
  1     2      (null)
  1     1      (null)
  2     1      (null)
  2     2      (null)
  2     8      (null)
  3     1      (null)
  3     2      (null)
  3     5      (null)
  3     6      (null)
  4     3      (null)
  4     6      (null)
  4     5      (null)
  4     2      (null)
```

I want a query to update my table as follows:

```
  COL1  COL2    COL3
  1     2        1
  1     1      (null)
  2     1        1
  2     2      (null)
  2     8      (null)
  3     1        1
  3     2      (null)
  3     5      (null)
  3     6      (null)
  4     3        1
  4     6      (null)
  4     5      (null)
  4     2      (null)
```

SQLFiddle schema link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ddce/1

Comment: What do you want to set for `col3`? Why it is 1 for all values?

Answer (score 0):

I tested this on your sample data and it works:

```
UPDATE  my_table

SET     col3 = 1

WHERE   col2 = (SELECT col2
                  FROM   my_table m
                  WHERE  m.col1 = col1
                  LIMIT 1
                 );
```

Answer (score -2):

If you don't mind getting errors in your updates, you can just define col1 as your primary key.  This will ensure that if col1 exists in your table, it cannot be added again.

Comment: @user11611218 This table is like result of many-to-many relation ship with one more extra attribute and I want col3 as true for distinct col1 which got created first.

Comment: You never specified that in your question.  The more details you provide, the better help you can get.  If all you say is that you don't want multiple insertions, you'll get an answer that addresses precisely that.

Comment: Yes I did, and I see no reason to change my answer.